# How to insert all rows data from a gridview to database when paging is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a `GridView` which adds **Products** from the `GridView` itself. I'm using the standard `ASP.Net` `DataGrid`. My question is, is there any way to insert all `DataRows` from a `GridView` to database when `paging` is used?

Comment: Paging should not influence the way you add datarows from gridview. The gridview has all the elements, even if at a moment in time only some elements are shown. Have you tried something and encountered a problem.

Comment: If i've 8 items and the pagsize is 5,then i think we'll get only 5 or 3 items depending on the index we selected

Comment: This should be no problem. You are one that makes the method that puts those 8 items in database. The gridview object ALWAYS has 8 values (DataRows), even if you see 5 or 3. You could try to put the code for inserting DataRows in GridView, maybe there we could help if you implementing something wrong.

Comment: i used foreach condition for iterating the gridview,but i got only 5 records(I thought it was because i was in first page)

Comment: Is your foreach a `foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)`? Because the right way is to iterate throught the datasource of the GridView, not the GridView itself.

Comment: Yeah i iterated through foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows).I think you are telling me to iterate through the datatable(which is the datasource of gridview) instead of gridview

Comment: Yes, you should iterate throught the datatable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16629/discussion-between-ksg-and-coral-doe)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Coral is right paging should no way influence insert operation.

If you are encountering any issue you can post.